# SP2010 Database Server Shown in CA Not Found in Farm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, central-administration, database-server

Under 'Manage Content Database Settings' in Central Administration, where it says 'Database Information' on the left, is a name under 'Database server' on the right that I do not recognize, say DBCA. There is a database server in the farm with all the right databases, but that server has a different name, say DBSQL. I have looked at the Server Configuration Manager on DBSQL for aliases, but there are none. Also, SSMS does not see a server by the name DBCA anywhere on the network.

The site is working. My SharePoint experience has focused on development rather than administration, but I ran across this troubleshooting another issue, and it has me stumped. Can anyone shed some light on how this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of thing you can try to solve the mystery.

1. open the command prompt and ping dbcs, you will get ip if it is correct. Tum command prompt on SharePoint server as well.
2. Check the host file on the SharePoint server, maybe someone has entry which points to dbsql.
3. From central admin..system settings..cluck on manger server in this farm...check which db server listed here.
4. Also Check on the SharePoint servers, if someone configured the SQL Alias on the servers.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks Waqas Sarwar. Here is what I found when I tried them: 1) DBCA does not ping, DBSQL does. Not sure what you mean by "Turn command prompt on SharePoint server as well. 2) No entry for DBCA in host file. 3) DB server listed in 'Servers in Farm' is also DBCA.

Comment: i mean ping the DBCA from SharePoint server? do you have SQL Alias Configured on the SharePoint server

Comment: follow this guid to test the connection...https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/priyo/2013/09/13/sql-alias-for-sharepoint/  dont create new entry just check it

Comment: The suggestion to "follow this guide..." solved the mystery. Basically, the guide involves running the "SQL Server Client Network Utility" which I did not know about. Clicking the "Alias" tab in this utility showed an alias of DBCA mapped to DBSQL. Putting this together with what I know about the farm's backup policy, I conclude this was done to simplify switching over to the backup database in the event of the primary's failure. Thank you so much!

Comment: great, i am happy we able to resolve the mystery.  This is one of the best practice that create sql alias to make DR or failover easy.